# CStarRating Fails to save to database

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to save rating in db but it fails where as if I place a value in database table it successfully retrieves it and shows.

In my `$model->rating` is the rating of person in that table.

This is the code

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'rating'); ?>
    <?php echo $model->rating;
                $this->widget('CStarRating',array(
                    'model'=>$model,    
                    'attribute'=>'rating',
                     'maxRating'=>5,
                    'starCount'=>5,
                    'readOnly'=>false,
        )); ?>  
    </div>
```

Comment: your code is fine, as in it works, if you still want some help, then i think it's a problem with your controller or model. so if you still need help, you could put up that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that you need to put the variable rating in array with `safe` so that i can make changes to database.`array('rating', 'safe'),`